# How can I send a 404 when user tries to access a protected directory?

Tags: configuration, apache2

I'm running apache 2.4, and have a directory that can only be accessed from a certain IP address via the following:

```
<Directory /path/to/private/dir>
  Require ip 11.22.33.44
</Directory>
```

I would like anyone trying to access that URL to receive a 404 NOT FOUND rather than a 403 ACCESS DENIED.  Is there a way to do this via apache?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like this using `mod_rewrite`

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^11.22.33.44$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/path/to/private/dir.*$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```